# Python segmentation Unet

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I have the augmentation func

```
from albumentations import (
    CLAHE, RandomRotate90, Transpose, RandomCrop, Resize, ShiftScaleRotate, Blur, OpticalDistortion, 
    GridDistortion, HueSaturationValue, IAAAdditiveGaussianNoise, GaussNoise, MotionBlur, 
    MedianBlur, IAAPiecewiseAffine, IAASharpen, IAAEmboss, RandomContrast, RandomBrightness, 
    Flip, HorizontalFlip, OneOf, Compose, PadIfNeeded, LongestMaxSize, PadIfNeeded, ElasticTransform,Cutout
)

def strong_aug(p=1.0):
    return Compose([
        ShiftScaleRotate(shift_limit=0.125, scale_limit=0.2, rotate_limit=10, p=0.7, border_mode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT),
        #RandomCrop(256, 256),
        #PadIfNeeded(min_height=224, min_width=224, border_mode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, p=1.0),
        #Resize(64, 64),
        #RandomRotate90(),
        ElasticTransform(1.), 
        #HorizontalFlip(),
        #Cutout(p=1.),
        #Transpose(),
        OneOf([
            IAAAdditiveGaussianNoise(),
            GaussNoise(),
        ], p=0.3),
        OneOf([
            MotionBlur(p=.4),
            MedianBlur(blur_limit=3, p=0.3),
            Blur(blur_limit=3, p=0.3),
        ], p=0.5),
        OneOf([
            OpticalDistortion(p=0.3),
            GridDistortion(p=0.1),
            IAAPiecewiseAffine(p=0.3),
        ], p=0.5),
        OneOf([
            CLAHE(clip_limit=3),
            IAASharpen(),
            IAAEmboss(),
            RandomContrast(),
            RandomBrightness(),
        ], p=0.4),
        HueSaturationValue(p=0.7),
         
        
        
    ],
        p=p)
```

And when I try to use it, i get the mistake ("TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple") after this (step - Y_DICT_TRAIN[img_id]) :

```
import cv2
# all availiable ids: from "01" to "24":
trainIds = [str(i).zfill(2) for i in range(1, 25)]  

X_DICT_TRAIN = dict()
Y_DICT_TRAIN = dict()
X_DICT_VALIDATION = dict()
Y_DICT_VALIDATION = dict()

print('Reading images')
for img_id in trainIds:
    img_m = normalize(tiff.imread(f'{DATA_PATH_PREFIX}/mbandd/{img_id}.tif').transpose([1, 2, 0]))
    imf_m= strong_aug(img_m)
    mask = tiff.imread(f'{DATA_PATH_PREFIX}/gt-mbandd/{img_id}.tif').transpose([1, 2, 0])/255
    mask=strong_aug(mask)
    train_xsz = int(0.75 * img_m.shape[0])  # use 75% of image as train and 25% for validation
    X_DICT_TRAIN[img_id] = img_m[:train_xsz, :, :]
    Y_DICT_TRAIN[img_id] = mask[:train_xsz, :, :]
    X_DICT_VALIDATION[img_id] = img_m[train_xsz:, :, :]
    Y_DICT_VALIDATION[img_id] = mask[train_xsz:, :, :]
    print(img_id + ' read')
print('Images were read')

gc.collect();
```

How to solve this? I would be very grateful if you could help me figure this out, I tried the astype("uint8") method but that didn't help

Comment: Why do you try to use a tuple as list index?

Comment: i can't understand where is turple

Comment: The error message is telling you `img_id` is tuple.

Comment: I don't see where id becomes turple, if i delete mask=strong_aug(mask) all will be ok but i suppose i should use augmentation func with mask too